# Any reason not to enable CODE_ANALYSIS in production builds?

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop

Are there any performance costs when static code analysis is enabled in a production (release) build?

Our CI server runs code analysis on a debug build of our C# projects, whereas the release build has static code analysis disabled (i.e. CODE_ANALYSIS not defined). If there's no reason to disable code analysis on production builds, then I'm wasting time with the debug build.

Reflector shows me that `SuppressMessage` attributes are excluded if code analysis is disabled, but I don't expect the extra attribute to affect run-time performance. Is that the only effect of enabling static code analysis (in Visual Studio 2013)?

Comment: I think you're looking at this from the wrong angle. Code analysis will likely give better results on unoptimised IL (debug builds) than on optimised IL (release builds).

Comment: When you've come far enough to be ready to build and deploy the release build to production, still having to fix warnings from code analysis that may well require a significant code restructuring and re-testing of the changes is a very unproductive way to go about it.  Perf is not an issue.

Comment: @hvd That was part of my original thinking, but I can't find any evidence that code analysis gives different results in debug vs release builds. Can you?

Comment: @Hans We run code analysis while compiling, and our CI server stops the build chain long before deployment if any warnings are found during code analysis, so no worries there.

Comment: Static code analysis is just that - static. It runs as a build process step. There's no reason to run that build process step on a build which may have an obfuscator running on it, and every reason not to run it on such a build.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are actual differences when compiling with the `CODE_ANALYSIS` keyword enabled, for example, [the compiler will remove all `[SuppressMessage]` attributes from the assembly when it is not enabled](https://web.archive.org/web/20190303040847/http://sticklebackplastic.com/category/FxCop.aspx) (and may thus cause messages to show up when you run FxCop later from the command line, since the Suppressions have been removed). If you're installing your binaries on a internal system, it may be fine to leave the suppressions in the binaries. Some companies want them removed from assemblies released to 3rd parties, since the presence of these attributes (and the contents of the Justification properties) might disclose sensitive information.

When running Code Analysis on a `DEBUG` build you might get stricter results, certain optimizations that occur in most `RELEASE` builds can cause specific FxCop rules to get lost. The optimization may remove private methods (through inlining) or replace calls to constants with the value, instead of the definition of the constant. It will not be possible for FxCop to validate these items, since they have been removed. This is to be expected.

For best results: Run Code Analysis in a Debug build. For least information disclosure, remove the `CODE_ANALYSIS` constant from Release builds.

Comment: Dead link in answer

Comment: Updated to web archive.